# reuse of old packages with catkin

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ros-electric, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a few packages that were created using roscreate-pkg under Electric. Now, due to the use of other hardware (armhf) and driver availability, I have to use Hydro. Since this uses catkin instead of rosbuild, I wonder if the packages can be used just like that or have to be recreated using catkin-create-pkg.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165196/reuse-of-old-packages-with-catkin/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can convert packages to catkin (basic description of that process [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild)). You can also still use rosbuild packages with hydro, in which case you´d want to use a dual workspace setup that uses a rosbuild workspace on top of a catking one as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace). Both options require some amount of understanding the basics, but shouldn´t take too long to implement.  That is, at least if your package does not have (many) rosbuild dependencies. If it has, that means you also have to convert all dependencies to catkin, which could be a very involved process in the worst case.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-15**:
What I understand from your explanation is that I don't even have to use catkin on Hydro but can keep using rosbuild. If so, this would safe me a lot of work and possible problems.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-05-15**:
Yes. You can still use rosbuild. But, if you want to use both catkin and rosbuild packages, it is quite straight-forward to do so. Please see the second "here" in Stefan's answer.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-15**:
Ok, thank you.